# Please help..Anyone know how can I make a chart to sum all the data of each week only if values are greater than 0?

Tags: excel, windows-vista, charts, excel-formula

Basically I have a table like this:

```
Week   |   Value
1      |      2
2      |      3
2      |     -1
2      |      1
2      |      1
3      |      4
3      |      2    
6      |      4
7      |      1
```

I need a chart to show the sum of the values for each week only if the value is greater than 0.
so

- week 1 --> 2
- week 2 --> 5
- week 3 --> 6
- week 6 --> 4
- week 7 --> 1

Anyone have any idea how to do this?

Comment: Are you wanting a real excel graphical chart, or do you just want another table at a different spot in the spreadsheet with the data?

Comment: Well I've done both now... Basically I can make a table that sums all the values for any given week but I can't get it to count only values above 0? 

I used the SUMIF function to make the table and then my bar chart feeds off of that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have Excel 2007/2010, you can use the newer function SUMIFS as below:
=SUMIFS(Week_Values,Week_Numbers,This_Week2,Week_Values,">0")

Answer (score 0):

This is two criteria, so you either need an intermediate column, or an array formula.

### Option 1 - Extra Column:

Add a 3rd column, which has `=IF(This_Value>0,This_Value,0)` (where This_Value is the cell for that row with the value in it) and then do your SUMIF on the week number to sum up the new column; OR

### Option 2 - Array Formula:

For each week number as This_Week in its own cell: `=SUM(IF((Week_Numbers=This_Week)*(Week_Values>0),Week_Values,0))` which you must finish up with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of just Enter.  More on Array Formulas at [cpearson.com](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/lists.htm) and [Microsoft](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/275165).

Answer (score 0):

When you have more than one condition you could use **SUMPRODUCT** (simpler than Array formulas).
In this case suppose you have the data you propose on the cells **A1:B10** (with column names Weeks and Values in A1:B1).
then put in **D2** the number of the week for which you want the sum (say: 2)

Then:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($A$2:$A$10=$D2)*($B$2:$B$10>0)*$B$2:$B$10)
```

would do.

PS: be aware that you must esclude the column names from the selection of SUMPRODUCT (i.e. do not use $A$1:$A$10 in the above formula)